# How can I write meaningful unit tests around the Braintree Java API?

Tags: java, unit-testing, braintree

I am writing a payment gateway based upon the Java API for Braintree Payments (version 2.71.0 as of writing).

I would like to write unit tests to check that the requests I send to Braintree have the right parameters set. However, it seems that the objects exposed by the Java API are write-only.

Note that I don't want my automated tests to depend upon the availability of the Braintree sandbox: I want to write robust unit tests, not flaky system tests.

In a perfect world, I would like to be able to write something like this (using Mockito and AssertJ):

```java
BraintreeGateway mockGateway = Mockito.mock(BraintreeGateway.class);
TransactionGateway transactionGateway = Mockito.mock(TransactionGateway.class);
Result<Transaction> mockResult = (Result<Transaction>) Mockito.mock(Result.class);

BigDecimal totalAmount = BigDecimal.valueOf(1234, 2);
String customerId = "some-customer-id";

Mockito.when(mockGateway.transaction()).thenReturn(transactionGateway);
Mockito.when(transactionGateway.sale(any())).thenReturn(mockResult);

underTest.performTransaction(totalAmount, customerId);

ArgumentCaptor<TransactionRequest> reqCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(TransactionRequest.class);
Mockito.verify(transactionGateway).sale(reqCaptor.capture());

TransactionRequest sentRequest = reqCaptor.getValue();
Assertions.assertThat(sentRequest.getAmount()).isEqualTo(totalAmount);
Assertions.assertThat(sentRequest.getCustomer().getId()).isEqualTo(customerId);
```

Alas, the only methods I get on the `sentRequest` are setters.

As a workaround, I could try to mock one level deeper and catch the HTTP requests sent by the Braintree API, but that would be hardly readable and (once again) quite flaky.

Any better idea?

Answer (score -1):

I'd wrap the Braintree API into a seperate interfaces and write an integration test for the API, to test the *expected behavior*. That way you have an integration test to run, when the backend changes (in terms of API, technology and version), you can run smoke tests after a deployment and you can mock the new interface away in your unit test. You shouldn't - actually you can't by definition - *unit test* a third party system.

What does your test actually test anyway (what's underTest)? It looks it only tests your mocking and argument capturing.

... And if something is hardly readable, it's usually the writers fault :P

Comment: Thank you for making my point: we wrote a wrapper around BT's API, for which we can provide mocks or stubs for the rest of the system. But I'm aiming for the last mile (at least on our side): test that what we pass to BT is what will give us the expected behavior once in production.

Comment: Mmmh, I think I answered that, didn't I? Since you have wrapped the API behind an interface, you can test the interface with the actual implementation. And since that interface provides all functionality you use, you can take that test case and run it everywhere with the corresponding backend... and as I mentioned, you can put that test case everywhere in your delivery/build chain, after unit tests or before test deployment... or what am I missing?